# Missing languages in TTS android

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I am working on an android application that uses the TextToSpeech functionality provided by google and have followed this example:

[TTS Example from Google](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/TextToSpeechActivity.html)

I want to know with this line:

```
int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
        result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
        // Lanuage data is missing or the language is not supported.
    }
```

What can I do if the Language data is missing off the users device? The app will not continue if the data is not there? Is there a way to allow the user to get the language on their device? I have a test device that seems to not have any languages on it at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html:

```
// missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
```

No good way to know exactly what happens if the language they want simply doesn't exist at all, but....that is the recommended way of dealing with it.

Comment: URL has died.  :( Try https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html?m=1

Comment: Yes, you can download the languages, but how to get them working as a new language downloaded and how can we choose that language as default?

Comment: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.tts.engine.INSTALL_TTS_DATA }