# No voice TTS in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In my application,  i didn't get any voice

This is my code,

public class AndroidTextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
private TextToSpeech tts;
private Button btnSpeak;
private EditText txtText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

    txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

    // button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        // tts.setPitch(5); // set pitch level

        // tts.setSpeechRate(2); // set speech speed rate

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
        } else {
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
            speakOut();
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }

}

private void speakOut() {

    String text = txtText.getText().toString();

    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

}
```

}

i got an error in log cat

Language is not supported

any one help me?? and i need to highlight word when speaking

Comment: any exceptions, details, bug trace ?

Comment: working on emulator .. but not working device

Comment: Language is not supported

Comment: i got solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087187/text-to-speech-works-on-emulator-but-not-on-phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an solution, the problem was that the locales available on the android default tts engine did not match those on my phone. I installed another tts engine and it works perfectly fine with it.

or

```
 // missing data, install it
    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
    installIntent.setAction(
    TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
    startActivity(installIntent);
```

Refs:

- [SO: Missing languages in TTS android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913188/missing-languages-in-tts-android)
- [SO: Text to speech works on emulator but not on phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087187/text-to-speech-works-on-emulator-but-not-on-phone)